# copying the address of ifaddr to an ifreq struct

Tags: c, freebsd, mac-address

I have to get the MAC address of my interface and I use an *ifaddr* struct with *getifaddrs*. And it's working fine. But for the rest of my work, I'm using an *ifreq* struct. So i need to copy the address from the first struct, to the second one. 
I found out that the *sockaddr* struct in ifaddr, is of pointer, but not the same thing with *ifreq*. And when i copy the *sa_data* array, i see that the values differ.
This is the code I have:

```
struct ifreq ifr;
struct ifaddrs *tempifs, *po;
getifaddrs(&tempifs);
for(po = tempifs; po != NULL; po = po->ifa_next)
{

    if(!strcasecmp(po->ifa_name,ifr.ifr_name))
    {
        wpa_printf(MSG_DEBUG, "found it");
        if(po->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK)
        {
            unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char *)po->ifa_addr->sa_data + 12;

            printf("%s:%d %d %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",
                                (po)->ifa_name,
                                po->ifa_addr->sa_family,
                                po->ifa_addr->sa_len,
                                *ptr, *(ptr+1), *(ptr+2), *(ptr+3), *(ptr+4), *(ptr+5));

            ifr.ifr_addr.sa_len = po->ifa_addr->sa_len;
            ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_LINK;
            strcpy(ifr.ifr_addr.sa_data, po->ifa_addr->sa_data);

            unsigned char *ptr1 = (unsigned char *)&ifr.ifr_ifru.ifru_addr.sa_data + 12;
            printf("%s:%d %d %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",
                                (ifr).ifr_name,
                                ifr.ifr_ifru.ifru_addr.sa_family,
                                ifr.ifr_ifru.ifru_addr.sa_len,
                                *ptr1, *(ptr1+1), *(ptr1+2), *(ptr1+3), *(ptr1+4), *(ptr1+5));

        }
        break;
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
gbeth0:18 56 6c:f0:49:b3:60:1b
gbeth0:18 56 00:00:12:00:00:00
```

18: is the sa_family (which is AF_LINK)
56: is the sa_len

There must be something wrong with the copying, but I can't find it.
Thanks,

**NOTE**
Also, I'm on FreeBSD. that's why i'm not using: *ifr.ifr_hwaddr*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `strcpy` for copying binary data, use `memcpy` instead. The `strcpy` stops at the first zero byte.